# Is "strictly" in the right place in this sentence? ("will strictly be dealt with")

Tags: grammar, word-order

*Those who do not reach the venue by 9 AM, **will strictly be** dealt with a penalty.*

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? Specifically the positioning of ***'strictly'***

Comment: I would probably say "will be strictly dealt with", or "will be dealt a penalty". Ajax, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: Because of the phrasing it sounds like, despite the meaning of the word *strictly*, it's trying to say that people will be *promptly* dealt with. Given the sentence structure and the word's placement, that's what my mind wants to translate it into.

Comment: No; never, and that's nothing to do with the position of "strictly".

In "Those who do not reach the venue by 9 AM, will strictly be dealt with a penalty" the word "strictly" adds confusion; nothing else.

To make that English, you might use "… be dealt with *by* penalty" but do you see no difference?

Comment: The problem here is that the sentence does not make sense. The *strictly* is a red herring for the real problem; delete it and notice that the sentence isn't grammatical.

Comment: I'll suspend my usual dislike for the suffix "-ize" and point out that "dealt with a penalty" is a certainly awkward and possibly ungrammatical way to say "penalized".

Answer (score 1):

The intended meaning is not completely clear. One possible meaning is that all latecomers will be penalised - no exceptions. That would be applying the rules **strictly**. Another possible, but less likely, meaning is that exceptions may be allowed: the sense of strictly being that "that is what the rules say, but we have discretion to be lenient". That sense is more often seen in the expression "strictly speaking...".

You do not say why you ask the question. The sentence does read slightly oddly to me, but there is no rule that prohibits placing an adverb as strictly is placed in that sentence. To see that, replace 'strictly' with 'generally' and you get an unexceptionable sentence.

So if there is a problem, apart from slight ambiguity, it is not grammatical, but a matter of style. The sentence might be improved stylistically by moving 'strictly' to follow with.